# How to read each field into an array properly?

Tags: php

I have this structure in a csv file

```
"http://example.com/example.jpg","example","example2","example3","1234,56"
```

Now I assign this line to a variable $line and

```
$fields = explode('","',$line);
```

It stops at "http". The same with

```
$fields = csv2array(str_replace(':','\\:',$line),$delimiter=',',$enclosure='"',$escape='\\');
```

where

```
function csv2array($input,$delimiter=',',$enclosure='"',$escape='\\'){ 
     $fields=explode($enclosure.$delimiter.$enclosure,substr($input,1,-1)); 
     foreach ($fields as $key=>$value) 
         $fields[$key]=str_replace($escape.$enclosure,$enclosure,$value); 
     return($fields); 
 }
```

How to read each field into an array?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the file using fgetcsv() which returns an array of values exactly as you want.